# Global styling vs local styling in VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm building a project with `.vue` files which make it possible to write the CSS (SASS), JS and HTML in the same file.

I've decided to have some global components written in SASS on a `assets/styles/app.scss` file which will load my grid, variables and mixins.

On top of that, I want to be able to write some local SASS rules depending the component / page I'm on, seems pretty logical to want both in a project ...

Locally it looks like this:

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "assets/styles/app";

  .my-style {
    color: $my-variable;
  }
</style>
```

It actually works, for instance I can use `$my-variable` in my local `.vue` file or any mixin I want. The problem is a VueJS project will grow and components will go together to display a page.

I noticed the global styling was loaded on each component, and the same rule is present in 5x, 10x when I open my chrome developer tool. This is still a very small project; all my styles are basically duplicated and loaded by the browser each time I add a component to the same page.

How do you avoid to load multiple times the global styles, while being able to use global SASS code in each components?

I've never worked with local mixed with global styling before, I preferred to just abstract totally the styling into a separated structure, but this is way more convenient to code with everything local in the same place.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: duplicate styling on the page]

Detail: I'm on NuxtJS but I believe this issue is more related to VueJS overall.

Comment: Did you create this using Vue CLI 3 or with a previous version? It changes how you implement the global SCSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, for this project I'm using NuxtJS so they handle it as a kind of blackbox, but the project is brand new from a few weeks if that can help ...

Comment: On production mode, you can [extract component css](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Extracting-Component-CSS). All the css will be bundled into a single file and loaded once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, every time you do an `@import` in your components it appends another copy to the main CSS file that Webpack generates.

Assuming you have the Webpack SCSS loader properly configured (which I believe you do since it compiles), you should be able to import the SCSS file once in your `app.vue` and the SCSS compiler will find it when it appends all other CSS.

For example, getting global fonts and mixins:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&subset=latin-ext');
  @import "@/scss/mixins.scss";
</style>
```

Then create your CSS for each component inside the component's `<style>` section. Just make sure you add the `lang="scss"` so it all compiles.

You might also want to look into [scss-resource-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) for Webpack. I think this is in the newest CLI builds, not sure about Nuxt.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have an `app.vue` because I'm using NuxtJS but this the beginning  of a solution ... I'll try to find the equivalent and see if that works :)

Comment: Take a look at my edit. That Webpack loader might help you.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, `app.vue` or the highest level component in your project is where mixins should go. Then they "cascade" to the other components that get loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

in `App.vue`

```
<style lang="scss">

@import "assets/styles/common.scss";

</style>
```

OR

import compiled sass to css file in `main.js`

```js
import './assets/styles/common.css';
```